# PHP MySQL Update database with AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I will describde the problem as straight as I can, so:

I've got website, on which I have button, by clicking which I want to run AJAX, which would run .php code which will update database records.

Right now, with code below Im not getting any errors, and also database is at the same state as it was before clicking button. What's more I guess that ajax doesnt works properly, as the website refreshes as I click update button.

Any 1? Anything?

Here goes main php (updated):

```
<form role='form' method='post' action='' autocomplete='off'>
                        <input type='submit' id='addBidSlow' name='addBidSlow' value='Slow bid' class='btn btn-inline-block btn-success auctionDetails' tabindex='1'>
                    </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#addBidSlow").click(function(){
                var bidAuthor = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
                var itemID = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>;
                $.post(
                    "addBidSlow.php",
                    {bidAuthor: bidAuthor, itemID: itemID},
                    false
                );
            });
        </script>
```

And updater php:

```
<?php
    require('includes/config.php');

        $bid = 1000;
        $bidAuthorPoints = "";
        $finalPoints = "";
        $finalDate = "";
        $todayDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT itemID, endTime FROM items WHERE itemID = :itemID");
        $stmt->execute(array(':itemID' => $itemID));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $finalDate = $row->endTime;
        }

        $addedTime = strtotime($finalDate) + 60*10;
        $finalDate2DB = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , $addedTime);

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE items SET endTime = :finalDate2DB WHERE itemID = :itemID");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':itemID' => $itemID,
            ':finalDate2DB' => $finalDate2DB
        ));
?>
```

Comment: You send data with POST but check in GET, are you sure what you're doing?

Comment: What is the value of `$itemID`?

Comment: @u_mulder with POST the result is the same.

Comment: @u_mulder value of $itemID is ID assigned to the link of the page which You are currently viewing, for example in this case its 15 (website.com/page.php?id=15)

Comment: In your code `$itemID` is __not set anywhere__

Comment: Well, so how would you @u_mulder describe the fact, that when typing **print_r($_GET['id']);** or **print_r($itemID);** I get 15? And about which code You are talking about, main or updater .php

Comment: You should return false in your click event listener to prevent it from posting to the url defined in the form action

Comment: @GraemeChapman with   
                    $.post(
                        "addBidSlow.php",
                        {bidAuthor: bidAuthor, itemID: itemID},
                        false
                    );
It still doesn't works.

Comment: That's not what I meant... After the line closing the $.post, add another line with `return false;`. Not necessarily a fix for the problem but this is the reason why it's refreshing the page.

Comment: @GraemeChapman You are right, thanks, now its not refreshing window.